# Play .wma from memory stream using NAudio

Tags: c#, memory, stream, naudio, wma

I'm working on a C# app in Visual Studio 2013 that needs to play audio files in .wav, .mp3 and .wma formats. the .wav and mp3 files play with no problem. .wma files, however, seem to require extra handling and I'm at a loss to find a solution.

Here are the using statements at the top of the project file:

```
using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.FileFormats.Wav;
using NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3;
using NAudio.WindowsMediaFormat;
using NAudio.MediaFoundation;
```

And here's the code for playback:

```
    private void PlayIntroScreenAudio()
    {
        Player.Stop();
        byte[] IntroAudioInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(GameInfo.IntroScreenAudio);
        MemoryStream msIntroAudioStream = new MemoryStream(IntroAudioInBytes, 0, IntroAudioInBytes.Length);
        msIntroAudioStream.Write(IntroAudioInBytes, 0, IntroAudioInBytes.Length);
        msIntroAudioStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        msIntroAudioStream.Position = 0;

        if (GameInfo.IntroScreenAudioFileExt == ".wav")
        {
            WaveFileReader wfr = new WaveFileReader(msIntroAudioStream);
            Player.Init(wfr);
        }
        else if (GameInfo.IntroScreenAudioFileExt == ".mp3")
        {
            Mp3FileReader mp3rdr = new Mp3FileReader(msIntroAudioStream);
            Player.Init(mp3rdr);
        }
        else if (GameInfo.IntroScreenAudioFileExt == ".wma")
        {
            WMAFileReader wmafr = new WMAFileReader(msIntroAudioStream);
            Player.Init(wmafr);
        }
        Player.Play();
        IntroAudioIsPlaying = true;
        FinalScoreAudioIsPlaying = QuestionAudioIsPlaying = CARAudioIsPlaying = IARAudioIsPlaying = false;
        btnPlayIntroScreenAudio.Image = Properties.Resources.btnStopIcon;
        btnPlayFinalScoreAudio.Image = btnPlayQuestionAudio.Image = btnPlayCorrectResponseAudio.Image =
            btnPlayIncorrectResponseAudio.Image = Properties.Resources.btnPlayIcon;
        Player.PlaybackStopped += Player_PlaybackStopped;
    }
```

As you'll probably guess, I get a wiggly line under "(msIntroAudioStream)". I tried adding ".ToString() inside the parentheses, but VS says it's wrong, since wmafr can't read from a string. What other code do I need to play a .wma file?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I added tags, but not to the title. How'd that happen?

Comment: I mean you had "C#" at the end of the title. It seemed to be saying the same thing as the C# tag in the tags.

Comment: Actually, John, I added "C#" so that others would know what language I'm working in, since Visual Studio handles other languages as well. Sorry if that caused any confusion.

Comment: And that's exactly what tags are for, so in the future, please keep that sort of information out of the titles, and instead use the tags.

Answer (score 1):

`WMAFileReader` only supports input from a file and it expects a string representing a path to file in its constructor's argument.

If you want to use `WMAFileReader`, you would have to write your `MemoryStream` to a file first, and then feed the path to `WMAFileReader`.

Curiously enough, `WMAFileReader` has no constructor taking a `Stream` as an argument, but `Mp3FileReader` and `WaveFileReader` both do.